# Modify upload.aspx to display an additional text

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, document-library, file-upload

In our SharePoint 2013 application we have developed a feature to limit max upload file to 250 MB.

Now this feature works in some Internet Explorer versions and doesn't work in others, as a result we have decided to scrap this feature and instead put a small text on upload.aspx informing the users about the file size limit.

Request your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got following solution from MSDN :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/_layouts/15/upload.aspx') > 0) 
 {
  $('input:checkbox').closest("td").append("The files uploaded no more than 250MB");
 }
});  
</script>
```

The above code should be integrated in the "upload.aspx" MasterPage.

Comment: Please do not post link only answers! Instead include the details in your answer, to make it more useful for future readers

Comment: @RobertLindgren have edited the post as per your suggestion.

Comment: Great! :) But you should leave the link in your post as well as a source

Answer (score -1):

There is a workaround to add text to the Upload.aspx. Add following javascript code to your masterpage:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/_layouts/15/upload.aspx') > 0) {
        jQuery('input:checkbox').closest("td").append("
Message for size limit");
    }
});
```

Above code will display message on all the upload pages. To show this message on particular document library upload page:

```
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_URL/_layouts/15/upload.aspx') > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Hemant .
I added following Java Script in Seattle and Oslo Master pages but I don't see any change in the upload.aspx page 

after -  <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />


Code - 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/custom.js">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() 
              {
                  if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/_layouts/15/upload.aspx') > 0) 
                     {    jQuery('input:checkbox').closest("td").append("Message for size limit");
      }
  });
  </script>

Comment: Make sure you have jquery reference added to your masterpage before the script block. Also add above code in regular script block under head tag.

Comment: Thanks Hemant. 
I got a solution on MSDN. Its similar to your suggestion.