# How to customize upload.aspx in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, document-library, office-365-developer

Is there a possibility to customize upload.aspx in SharePoint online.

If yes, Please let me know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible. It is layout page....

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, it is possible to customize. (Just don't get too excited, and keep on reading!)

It is for example possible to:

- [Add additional text to upload.aspx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109741/modify-upload-aspx-to-display-an-additional-text)
- Or just [create your own upload.aspx from scratch and use it](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/modification-of-layouts-upload-aspx)

However it is **not recommended** to modify the upload.aspx. Upload.aspx is used in everywhere of your site collection and is also a subject of possible updates, which could in the worst case break the upload.aspx's functionality, if not only override the done changes. Basically customizing upload.aspx requires a hack'ish approach which would set your environment to unsupported state from Microsoft's point-of-view.

Now that the warnings have been given, I understand that the second link technically doesn't modify the upload.aspx and it offers a customized action in a limited context. But I will give the responsibility to you whether you wish to give it a shot!

Comment: But in Sharepoint online layouts folder is maintained by microsoft how can we edit Upload form if there is no Layouts folder???

Comment: The first link shows a way where you only "inject" JS to the upload.aspx once it's open, so no problems there. The rely on the second, you indeed can't use a copy of the upload.aspx. Instead, you would be required a create a new page with SPD and handle the upload with e.g. JS client object model, jQuery, or REST. There are [examples of this](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery).

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct answer is **Yes, you can, but...**

Indeed you can edit it but I do not recommend it, since it is one for every library. It means the changes reflect on the upload.aspx of all libraries present in your farm.

As written as a comment of @moe, I suggest to create a new page and use CSOM to save the file. Here is the code I use:

```
var input = document.getElementById('theInputElemenetTypeFile');
if (input.files[0]) {

    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = ctx.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getById("Put the list guid here");

        var fileContent = input.files[0];
        var filename = "Put the filename here";

        var fci = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
        fci.set_url(filename); // set the filename
        fci.set_overwrite(true); // flag to overwrite a already existing file
        fci.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());

        // copy the file to the CSOM stream
        for (var i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++) {
            fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(fileContent.charCodeAt(i));
        }

        // add the file
        var file = list.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fci);

        // get the related listItem in order to add properties
        var item = file.get_listItemAllFields();

        // if needed add properties
        item.set_item("Property1", "bla bla");
        item.set_item("Title", filename);
        item.set_item("Property2", "bla bla bla");

        item.update();
        list.update();

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() { 

            // Do what to so when successful, I refresh the page...
            window.location.reload(true);

        }, function(request, error) { 
            // In case of an error...
            var msg = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("Nachricht:", "An error has occurred.");
            SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(msg, 'red');
            if (console && console.error){
                console.error(error);
            }
        })
    }, 'SP.js')
}
```