# Edit Upload Document Psage

Tags: sharepoint-server, file-upload

I need to change the wording from Add a document to Add your file when users uploading a file, can you please help me to find out how I can do this:

[image]

Comment: Online? Or which version of on-prem?

Comment: SharePoint 2016 on-prem

Answer (score 0):

This upload.aspx, is in the '_layouts/upload.aspx' folder in your SharePoint server, any changes you want to make in to this file must be replicated on each web front end. It'll take effect throughout the Site Collection(s) on that WFE. So any SharePoint update might revert the changes back to original version. So instead of making changes to this file, create a copy of this file and name it as `upload2.aspx`.  Keep it in the /layouts folder

Once you have the copy, you can make your modifications as you like. Final step will be pointing this new `upload2.aspx` in your document library upload menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jquery, get the id of level of the existing text, then customize the below code :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 { if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/_layouts/15/upload.aspx') > 0) { $('input:checkbox').closest("td").append("The files uploaded no more than 250MB"); } }); 
</script>
```

The above code should be integrated in the "upload.aspx" MasterPage.

Above code will display message on all the upload pages. To show this message on particular document library upload page:

```
location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_URL/_layouts/15/upload.aspx') > 0)
```

Similar question is here :

[Modify upload.aspx to display an additional text](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109741/modify-upload-aspx-to-display-an-additional-text)

Approach 2:

In the below location completely custom upload control is available, you can install this wsp.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/yetanothersharepointblog.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/customize-the-sharpoint-upload-page/amp/

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

Create a css file hosts in siteassets library.

[image]

```
#dialogTitleSpan {
text-indent: -9999px;
}


#dialogTitleSpan:before {
    text-indent: 0;
    content: 'Here is something else !';
    float: left;
}
```

Set the css file as below(Site settings->master page).

[image]
Result:

[image]